# MySQL : Unexpected values during update

Tags: mysql

Hello this is my first post in stack exchange.

I'm having a problem with my table named `vendor_clients`

In that table, there's a field named `credits` with a datatype of `float`

Now, I'm trying to execute this query:
`UPDATE vendor_clients SET credits = '8850094' WHERE client_id = '5';`

So I am expecting to have a `8850094` value of the row that has a `client_id = 5`

But the problem is, instead becoming `8850094` it becomes `8850100`. 
So I tried setting `credits` to `'8850082'`, but instead, it becomes `'8850080'`. Any help would be appreciated.

(I have all privileges in the table by the way)

EDIT: Also, the response to this query is:

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Whats is the datatype of `credits` ?

Comment: @Abhik It is `float`

Comment: '8850082' is a string and not an integer/float , have you tried without single quotes for credit value?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña Yeah I did, still the same

Comment: will you do the `desc vendor_clients` and paste the response here

Comment: @Amar There are 8 fields, but I will only post the `credits` field here.
Field: `credits` Type: `float` Null: `NO` Default: `NULL`

Comment: @KenthJohnIsrael define it as credit float(15,7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely your column definition isn't specifying the precision. Make sure the column is something like:

```
credits float(15,2)
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85156/1

Comment: Wow great. Thanks, now I understand. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the precision like this:

```
create table vendor_clients(client_id int, credits float(15,4));
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cd98/1)**

Also I would recommend you to use `Double` instead of `float`.

Comment: Thanks! I can now understand the problem. Too bad I don't have enough reputation to upvote this answer.